# Can Superman x-ray with his eyes closed?

Tags: dc, superman

Can Superman still x-ray behind stuff with his eyes closed?

Comment: Duplicate question. Please remove!!

Comment: @KlevinDelimeta don't worry duplicates aren't necessarily bad,

Comment: Also very related (maybe a better dupe target), [X-ray vision of superman: Is lead the only element stopping the ability?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/80849/58193)

Comment: @KlevinDelimeta You can delete your own question if you want to

Comment: Well if its against some sort of rule (which i never read) i will be happy to. But i don’t think it is. Edlothiad said “it’s not necessarily bad”